# How to disable Google chrome extension with javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup, togglebutton

I am a beginner in writing Google chrome  extension

I need to turn off and turn on the extension using this toggle in pop-up window of extension

(this code is located in popup.html):

```
     <label class="switch">
          <input class="switch" type="checkbox" />
          <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
```

This is code located in popup.js file:

```
  const switchButton = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');

  switchButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
   
     switchButton.checked ? continueWork() : stopWork();

   });

function continueWork() {}
function stopWork() {}
```

Can I using this method to solve my problem?

let settingEnabled = browser.management.setEnabled(
id,              // string
enabled         // boolean
)

Very sorry If my question is incorrect or I gave not full explanation

Comment: No, it's incorrect. The solution depends on what your extension does. Please describe it and show the relevant code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.